# How to use microsoft mvc membership when separating server and client sides

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, server-side

How can I use microsoft mvc membership provider and still keep my client side and server side separated ?

When I import the membership nuget package ( `OAuth` ) to my mvc project it adds context, models and many other things that should be on the server side .

Some things I can easily pass to the server side solution, but for E.G the `IdentityDbContext` is coming from MetaData and belongs to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` so i actually need to import this dll to my server side solution, but is it right to have an AspNet dll on the serve side ?

If anyone have done this before and can advice it will be great .

I could not find any manual out there..

Comment: I curious to know what you mean by server and client sides in the context of a Web application where 100% of the .Net code is executed by a server.

Comment: @HighCore : In my app there is a client side ( which is the views/presentation layer) and its backend ( the controllers ), beside that i have another solution which contains the DAL and BLL and Services layers . so the context should be there .